# webflux Mono<T> onErrorReturn not called

Tags: spring-webflux

this is my HandlerFunction

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> getTime(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return time(serverRequest).onErrorReturn("some errors has happened !").flatMap(s -> {
        // this  didn't called
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).syncBody(s);
    });
}
```

time(ServerRequest serverRequest) method is

```
private Mono<String> time(ServerRequest request) {
    String format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now());
    return Mono.just("time is:" + format + "," + request.queryParam("name").get());
}
```

when i don't using param "name",it will throw one NoSuchElementException;
But, the Mono onErrorReturn not working!
why or what do i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onError...` operators are meant to deal with error signals happening in the pipeline.

In your case, the `NoSuchElementException` is thrown outside of the reactive pipeline, before anything can subscribe to the returned `Mono`.

I think you might get the behavior you're looking for by deferring the execution like this:

```
private Mono<String> time(ServerRequest request) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> {
        String format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now());
        Mono.just("time is:" + format + "," + request.queryParam("name").get());
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! it does works! I'm one newer for webflux! thank you again